# Carousel String Offset in a button

Tags: php, sql, carousel

I am trying to create a carousel with button "Read More" in every slide, it should be redirect to an image however it is not fetching the data instead it shows an error when im trying to put the button Illegal string offset (image2) -"image2 is the row in my sql table"

This is the carousel script.

```
                                    <?php
                                    include "db.php";
                                    $query      = "select * from carousel1 order by id desc limit 10";
                                    $res        = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                                    $count      =   mysqli_num_rows($res);
                                    while($c=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

                                        $titlee  = $c['titlee'];
                                        $konten = $c['konten'];
                                        $gbr    = $c['image'];
                                        $gbr2    = $c['image2'];

                                        if($counter==0)
                                        {

                                            echo"<div class='item active'>";                                        
                                            echo    "<a href=''>";
                                            echo        "<img src='images/$gbr'>";

                                            echo    "</a>";
                                            echo    "<div class='container'>";              
                                            echo    "<div class='carousel-caption left-caption style='background-color:#EE0930'>";
                                            echo        "<a href=''> <font color=#ffffffff style='font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Georgia; font-size: 13px;'>";
                                            echo            "<h5 class='text-left'>".$titlee."</h5></font>";
                                            echo       "</a>";

                                            echo "<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\" href=\"{$gbr2["image2"]}\">Read More</a>";
                                            echo   "</div>";
                                            echo    "</div>";
                                            echo    "</div>";

                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            echo    "<div class='item'>";               
                                            echo        "<a href=''>";
                                            echo            "<img src='images/$gbr'>";
                                            echo        "</a>";                                         
                                            echo        "<div class='container'>";

                                            echo        "<div class='carousel-caption left-caption style='background-color:#EE0930'>";
                                            echo            "<a href=''> <font color=#ffffffff style='font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Georgia; font-size: 13px;'><h5 class='text-left'>".$titlee."</h5></font>
                                            </a>";
                                            echo "<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\" href=\"{$gbr2["image2"]}\">Read More</a>";                                
                                            echo    "</div>";
                                            echo    "</div>";
                                            echo    "</div>";
                                                    }
                                                    $counter++;
                                                    }

                                            echo"</div>";
                                            echo    "<a class='left carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' data-slide='prev'>‹</a>";
                                            echo    "<a class='right carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' data-slide='next'>&rsaquo;</a>";

                                            echo"</div>";

                                            echo"<!-- End Slider Caraousel-->";
                                            ?>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

The value of image2 is already being stored in $gbr2 ($gbr2    = $c['image2'];) . And then you're trying to use $gbr2["image2"] to get the value

Replace $gbr2["image2"] with  $gbr2

Comment: I change it to echo  "<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\" href='images/$gbr2' . target="_blank">'Read More</a>"; but still doesnt work is the target directory correct?

Comment: Have you tried the usual debug methods. What do you get when you var_dump $c array? Is the final file path you get correct for $gbr2?